# Tizen 3.0 Web Key in the Certificate of the Host is Mismatched to the Pinned Key

Tags: javascript, web, tizen

I am developing a Tizen web app that can download files from certain URL with `https://` protocol. The downloader I use is the default `tizen.download` API provided by Tizen. When it turned to the validation phase of Tizen Store, my app got rejected because the download feature does not work in Samsung's Z4 device.

The test video report from the store shows that my app's download process worked flawlessly in former Z devices (Z1, Z2, & Z3), but got stuck in Z4 without any error message nor alert. Lately I noticed that Z4 devices are powered by Tizen OS version 3.0 while the other devices use Tizen v2.4 and older.

So I began investigating the problem by deploying my app to a Tizen v3.0 emulator. When I tried to launch the download feature, an alert popped up displaying a message: `"Web Key in the Certificate of the Host [https://site-address.com] is Mismatched to the Pinned Key"`. I searched "Pinned Key" int the Tizen Developer site and figured out that it actually is a kind of new security feature newly implemented in Tizen 3.0, here is the screenshot:

[image]

When I click "allow" button, it gives no effect the and the alert keeps appearing. The download process is still fails. So, my question how can we (if possible) fix such problem?

*Note: I found that this problem will not occur if the URL protocol is `"http://"`

Answer (score 0):

I Tried this sample app on Tizen Studio:

New > Sample > Mobile 3.0 > Web > Content > DownloadManager

Deployed the app on Tizen 3.0 Mobile Emulator and downloaded packages  One example package:

download.tizen.org/sdk/samples/online/Web/MW_download-manager/MW_download-manager.zip

Works fine, I would suggest you to check out the source code of the app, May help.